# Is it okay to have a header tag link to a page?

Tags: xhtml, html, html-parsing

I'm a huge web standards advocate, but I have one question I'm a little stumped on; Is it alright to combine an anchor tag, and header tag?

Example

```
<h2><a href="link.html">My portfolio</a></h2>
```

I can't put my finger on it, but something deep down inside tells me there's a reason one shouldn't use this technique. (Maybe because of search engine parsing, etc?) What are your thoughts?

Comment: linking element is not preferable why not change to `<h2><a href="link.html">My portfolio</a></h2>`

Comment: Your particular question is answered below, but to generalize: you can always use the W3C validator: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have, an anchor inside an h2, is perfectly fine and is the most common way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly legal and okay. Search engines won't have trouble parsing that link.

Answer (score 0):

Using an href inside of an h2 is perfectly acceptable, but since it's a heading, it's likely that a link can be added somewhere else (maybe inside a `p` tag) because users do not usually expect links within headings.